# Django ORM concat for related rows (string join through ORM?)

Tags: django, django-orm

Two simple models:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    pass

class Message(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, related_name='messages')
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
>>> thread = Thread.objects.create()

>>> Message.objects.create(thread=thread, content='One')
>>> Message.objects.create(thread=thread, content='Two')
>>> Message.objects.create(thread=thread, content='Three')

>>> t = Thread.objects.annotate(
        message_content=MySuperConcat('messages__content')).first()
>>> t.messages_content

OneTwoThree
```

Seems like Django's Concat can't do this and now I'm not sure if desired behavior is possible at all.

Note: PostgreSQL 9.5 and Django 1.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Postgres, you can use `StringAgg` [[docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#stringagg), although, on version 1.11, you won't be able to order it.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
Thread.objects.annotate(arr=StringAgg('messages__content', delimiter='')).values()
>>> 'ThreeTwoOne'
```

UPDATE:

If you're not 100% set on the code being totally done through the ORM, it's pretty straight-forward to do something like

```
vals = Thread.objects.filter(id=1).annotate(m=F('messages__content')).order_by('messages__id').values('m')
''.join([x['m'] for x in vals])
>>> 'OneTwoThree'
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual way to resolve this problem is using **`aggregate`** method beside of `StringAgg` class:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import StringAgg
Thread.objects.aggregate(arr=StringAgg('messages__content', delimiter='')).values()
```